MATLAB var() function not working after another script is run
A = [4 -7 3; 1 4 -2; 10 7 9];
var(A)


Here is my code (taken straight from variance documentation.
When I open matlab and run the code, it works fine. BUT, when I run another script (lets call it script_2) and then go back and try to run the code again, I get the error: "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."
I did install the package "Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox" but then later uninstalled it through clicking: Home -> Manage add-ons, and then uninstalled it.
However it seemed to have not been working, and I suspect the uninstallation didn't do its job.
It could be that something in script_2 that installs something that overrides what the function var() does. But I've looked through the script and cant find anything.
Edit: I've tried boiling it down to where the var() function is altered by putting in the following:
A = [4 -7 3; 1 4 -2; 10 7 9]; disp(var(A)); 
at several places in script_2. It seems to be the following for loop that somehow interferes with the var() function:
`A = [4 -7 3; 1 4 -2; 10 7 9];
disp(var(A));%%%%%%%%%%%

for i = 2:10000
    mu = alpha + (X(i-1) - alpha)*exp(-beta*delta);
    var = (sigma^2/(2*beta))*(1-exp(-2*beta*delta));
    std = sqrt(var);
    X(i) = mu + std*randn;
end
%plot(1:10000,X)

A = [4 -7 3; 1 4 -2; 10 7 9];
disp(var(A));%%%%%%%%%%%`


You are defining a variable called var in that loop.  Why are you surprised that var() no longer works?

In particular, check the second point in the top answer of the linked Q&A.
